# LaTeX error for the command \begin{center}

Tags: math-mode

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}



\begin{center}
$dl_{a^{-1}}\circ d\varphi (v)\\
```

for the line I am getting the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

Comment: Many codes are missing. For example. \begin/\end{document}, $ and \end{center}. Have you checked all these?

Comment: Perhaps you lost a $ here $dl_{a^{-1}}\circ d\varphi (v)$\\

Comment: Do you want a centred formula? If so, you almost certainly want display math mode: `\[ dl_{a^{-1}}\circ d\varphi (v) \]`

Answer (score 1):

There is some code missing in your example. I made a minimal working example of it and it's compiling fine :

```
\documentclass[14pt]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  $dl_{a^{-1}}\circ d\varphi (v)$\\
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Beside of the missing `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` and `\end{center}` you forgot a `$` which was causing your error.